# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' in main.546ac9e6.chunk.js:1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

We have this web app that is built using create-react-app and was deployed. Now we get this error in our console.

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`

Most of the answers on StackOverflow speaks of webpack and all. We aren't using a webpack.

What can be the reason for this? How do we fix this?

Comment: FYI create-react-app uses webpack under the hood.

Answer (score 4):

Your server cannot find the `.js` file, and your web server is returning either a 404 page or the default `index.html`. That's why it says 'unexpected token <', from the `<DOCTYPE` tag. You should see what the response is in your network tab from the `main.chunk.js`, and also verify if it's loading from the correct location

Comment: check htaccess if you are deploying the build to an cpanel